# How to connect WebSocket to Android Applicaton?

Tags: android, websocket

I am new in Android. I want to make a demo where I can connect my mobile phone to Server which is running on Different computer. My Backend gave me WebSocket URL. I am implementing then I able to get browser message on my phone but I can't send message to server. What I did, its here. Please guide me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

connectWebSocket();

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}

private void connectWebSocket() {
URI uri;
try {
    uri = new URI("ws://xx.xxxxx.xxxxx.com:9000");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
        mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
        final String message = s;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
};
mWebSocketClient.connect();
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
mWebSocketClient.send(editText.getText().toString());
editText.setText("");
 }
 }
```

Comment: did you see any error in Logcat? i think onError function have been called when you sent message.

Comment: No I am not getting any Message in LogCat